# multiple MySQL queries across a web page layout - best way to go about it?

Tags: php, mysql

basically i'd like to know if it's preferable to establish a database connection before each database query, and then use mysqli_close() immediately after the relevant section, for every spot in the layout where database information has to be pulled - or if it's better to just open the database connection at the start of the file, and then use mysqli_close() near the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

One connection per request is more efficient. Only if you do many concurrent updates on the same rows is important to commit (close connection) as fast as posible.

Comment: There's an important distinction between closing a connection and committing a transaction. If you close a connection, you have to open a new connection which takes a large amount of time compared to other operations. Starting a transaction, on the other hand, is much quicker (and indeed, usually starts once you commit)

Comment: I agree with You. I'm DBA ... but php begginers almost always do not recognize difference between transaction and connection. RCT pattern - one Request, one Connection, one Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to just open the database connection at the start of the file, then get **all** the data, then use mysqli_close(), and then call a *template* to start displaying a page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection pooling, so it really doesn't matter how often you request a connection in the code.   Applications wishing to be scalable should avoid rapidly creating new connections, as they potentially could have noticeable overhead for encryption setup or waiting for a authentication server.